# JQuery DOM - element still referenced by old id

Tags: jquery, dom

I am changing the id of a modal button with this function

```
$('#editRevision a').click(function()
{   
    //clear the uploadify queue
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive('clearQueue');

    //change the id of the footer next button to pagesOrdered
    $('#next').attr('id' , 'pagesOrdered');
});
```

Just to check if the '.on('click',function()) is working I use the following

```
//Pages ordered click
$('#pagesOrdered').on('click',function()
{
     alert('Testing');
});
```

My alert is not firing, however if I change the `#pagesOrdered` back to `#next` it does fire. What do I need to do to release #next from the DOM.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#pagesOrdered')` doesn't exist when you call the code. You can add the click handler after you change `id` or delegate `on()` to higher level of the DOM tree and use `#pagesOrdered` as selector

first approach:

```
$('#editRevision a').click(function(){   
    //clear the uploadify queue
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive('clearQueue');

    //change the id of the footer next button to pagesOrdered
    $('#next').attr('id' , 'pagesOrdered');
    //Pages ordered click
    $('#pagesOrdered').on('click',function(){
     alert('Testing');
     });
});
```

second approach:

```
 $(document).on('click','#pagesOrdered',function(){
     alert('Testing');
 });
```

You should also unbind events attached to `#next` before changing `id`. Changing `id` won't remove them. Likely a simpler approach to what you are doing without changing `id` such as toggling a class and running class specific code in handler

Comment: Thanks a ton, I went with the second approach. I do need to explore more the unbinding of events. slowly but surely!